# How to pass variable in javascript to php with ajax

Tags: javascript, php, html, ajax

I'm trying to pass the selected month from select list in html with ajax. But every time I select a month, it didn't appear. Before I select a month there's a "nothing" because of `if else` conditional, then when I select a month the "nothing" word dissapear but no variable fetched.
Here's my javascript code:

```
$('#button-search-ohr').on('click', function() {
    var month = $('#monthChoose').val();

    if(month == 0) {
        alert('Month must be choosen!');
    }

    $.ajax({
        async   : true,
        type    : 'POST',
        url     : '<?php echo base_url();?>sms/lapkinerjastat', 
        data    : {month:month},
        success : function(data) {
            $('#month').html(data);
        }
    });
}
```

Here's the html and php

```
<h5 class="pilih-bulan">Month Choose
     <select id="monthChoose" name="month">
          <option value="0">Pilih bulan</option>
          <option value="Januari">Januari</option>
          <option value="Februari">Februari</option>
          <option value="Maret">Maret</option>
          <option value="April">April</option>
          <option value="Mei">Mei</option>
          <option value="Juni">Juni</option>
          <option value="Juli">Juli</option>
          <option value="Agustus">Agustus</option>
          <option value="September">September</option>
          <option value="Oktober">Oktober</option>
          <option value="November">November</option>
          <option value="Desember">Desember</option>
     </select>
     <button id="button-search-ohr" type="submit">Search</button>
</h5>    

<div id="month">
     <?php 
     if(isset($_POST['month'])) {
          $month = $_POST['month'];
          echo 'This is '.$month;
     }else {
          $month = null;
          echo 'Nothing';
     }?>
</div>
```

How do I do the proper way to passing variable in javascript to store that variable in php?

**EDIT :**
I realized I wrote the wrong `url` and I've just edited the `url` in javascript. It successfully pass the variable but the page become double. Here I got the screenshot.
Before select month (pay attention at "Nothing")

[image: before]

After select month (pay attention at "This is Februari")

[image: after]

Comment: All three codes are on single page?

Comment: please console.log month value, it is getting or  not ?

Comment: in $.ajax, what does this: `url: '<?php echo base_url();?>sms/upload_kinerja_ohr'` output? Have you checked it's correct / the request arrives where you expect it to?

Comment: Why you are echoing `<?php echo base_url(); ?>` in your ajax call?I suggest you to use an url instead.
Do you checked the console to see if there is any error?

Comment: What does `sms/upload_kinerja_ohr` do? Does it return anything? Can you post that code in your question please?

Comment: Try to change this `$('#button-search-ohr').on('click', function() {}` in this `$('#button-search-ohr').on('click', function(e) { e.preventDefault(); // your code }`

Comment: @AlivetoDie yes you're right.

Comment: @user9741470 I'm using codeigniter framework. Previously I've tried to write down the php file name directly but it didn't work.

Comment: @aan ok, I never used CI so I can't help you about this framework.

Comment: @kerbholz I've edited my question because unintentionally I wrote the wrong `url` in javascript.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**EDITED ANSWER**

When you click on your button you submit the form so you are redirected on same page.

Try this :

```
$('#button-search-ohr').on('click', function(e) { // Add the "e" in your function
    // You stop the submit
    e.preventDefault();
    e.stopPropagation();

    var month = $('#monthChoose').val();

    if(month == 0) {
        $('#month').html('Nothing');
         alert('Month must be choosen!');
    } else {
        $('#month').html('This is ' + month);
    }
}
```

And replace :

```
<div id="month">
     <?php 
     if(isset($_POST['month'])) {
          $month = $_POST['month'];
          echo 'This is '.$month;
     }else {
          $month = null;
          echo 'Nothing';
     }?>
</div>
```

By :

```
<div id="month">
    Nothing
</div>
```

You don't need to make an Ajax call to the same page to change the content of your div. Just switch from "Nothing" to the "This is " + the selected month.

Here is a snippet to show you : just click on your button and the content change :

```js
$('#button-search-ohr').on('click', function(e) { // Add the "e" in your function
    // You stop the submit
    e.preventDefault();
    e.stopPropagation();

    var month = $('#monthChoose').val();

    if(month == 0) {
        $('#month').html('Nothing');
         alert('Month must be choosen!');
    } else {
        $('#month').html('This is ' + month);
    }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h5 class="pilih-bulan">Month Choose
     <select id="monthChoose" name="month">
          <option value="0">Pilih bulan</option>
          <option value="Januari">Januari</option>
          <option value="Februari">Februari</option>
          <option value="Maret">Maret</option>
          <option value="April">April</option>
          <option value="Mei">Mei</option>
          <option value="Juni">Juni</option>
          <option value="Juli">Juli</option>
          <option value="Agustus">Agustus</option>
          <option value="September">September</option>
          <option value="Oktober">Oktober</option>
          <option value="November">November</option>
          <option value="Desember">Desember</option>
     </select>
     <button id="button-search-ohr" type="submit">Search</button>
</h5>

<div id='month'>
  Nothing
</div>
```

Comment: What do you get if you do `console.log(month);`? Do you have the right value?

Comment: @aan I change my answer. If you only want to change the content of your div month with the value of the selected month, no need to Ajax : just get the value and change the content. If nothing is selected, just display "Nothing" as you want

Comment: Thank you so much for your help. I managed to get the right value with ajax. I just need to change  `$('#month').html(data);` into `$('#month').html(month);`.Note the parameter.

Comment: If you do `$('#month').html(month);` in you Ajax success part, you don't need the Ajax...you get the `month` value BEFORE the Ajax part, so if you do what I wrote it will be the same :) The Ajax is useless if you don't use the `data` part ...

Comment: Np, glad if I helped you :) Don't forget to mark the question as solve if it works for you ;)